# I'm not able to revert a file while it's conflicting. git

Tags: git, revert

Here is what I've done:

- Create folder testA
- Create a file "a.txt" with it's contents "a"
- Git init into the folder testA
- git add .
- git commit -a -m "first"
- change the file's "a.txt" contents to "b"
- git add .
- git commit -a -m "changed to b"
- git log (to get the commit id of the "first" )
- git revert a90deafe08c9f8f0d7b94d3d74d40be2bd65b161

I get in console:

```
error: could not revert a90deaf... first
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Well, I would like to have all the files at the state of the previous commit, what should I do know?

UPDATE
**What I would want:**

- I would like to keep the "changed to b" commit and have a third one that is exactly the same as the "first" commit. I never ever want to lose any file.
- To work with binary files (see next point)
- I don't care how binary files are manage as long as I can have them in the state of the commit, so merge is not necessary in this case. I just want something easier: replace file A from commit X to commit Y, no complications with merge needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, get back to a good state with:

```
git revert --abort
```

Next, look at what you're asking.  `git revert` takes the commit id of the commit you want to undo.  The first commit sets `a.txt` to be:

```
a
```

The second commit makes it have:

```
b
```

And you want to revert the first commit.  So what that is saying is that you'd like to remove the addition of the `a` line, and the addition of the file which is a conflict.  The first commit added the file, and the second commit modified it.  So git doesn't know what to do now that you're asking to remove it.

I assume by "all the files at the state of the previous commit" that you want to get back to the state where `a.txt` has `a` in it.

There are a couple of ways to get back to the previous state.  If the commits have not been shared, you can simply use `git reset`:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

This says "reset the state of my working copy and index to the previous commit".  At this point, `a.txt` will have `a` in it.

If you had shared the second commit, then you *don't want to do the above*, because you'll be rewriting history, which causes a whole host of other issues.  Instead, revert the commit, like you were trying to do above, but use the right commit.  In this case, it's the HEAD commit you want to revert:

```
git revert HEAD
```

There are times when reverting a commit may conflict.  In that case, it's very much like merge conflicts.  You need to work through them, fixing up the conflicts and either using `git add` to stage the file with the modifications, or using `git rm` to remove the file.  Once you're done, `git revert --continue` will let the process finish.

### Update

The easiest way to go to restore the previous state, without having to do any fancy merging, is to use `git checkout`.  You can do:

```
git checkout HEAD~1 -- a.txt
git commit -m "Reverted to the previous version."
```

No merging, no fuss. :-)  `HEAD~1` can be any commit, of course.  I just used this based on the example you had.

Comment: But how exactly I manage the conflicts here? This is just an example with txt files, but it's pretended to be used with binary files so in order to manage conflicts I must be able to get my binary files somehow from the past, override the new one and commit. But how about 50 files, I can't do it everytime file by file?

Comment: Was it really the first commit that you wanted to revert?  Or was it simply that you wanted to drop the second commit and get back to the state of the first commit?  If so, then you won't have any merge conflicts (doing say would say "turn that `b` back into an `a`).  If you really did want to revert the first commit, and you're working with binary files, then you'll have problems in any VCS.  Binary files typically aren't mergable, so any VCS would look to you to resolve the conflicts since it can't automatically do it for you.  Perhaps it would be better to explain what you're doing instead.

Comment: Well, I've just updated my question, it was not very well defined in the first place.

Comment: Like the non-fancy approach!